# how to generate html report for multiple hosts using ansible and jinja2

Tags: html, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, jinja2-cli

my playbook

```
    - name: create HTML report
      template:
        src: report.j2
        dest: /cktreport.html
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

report.j2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>HOSTNAME</th>
            <th>PORT</th>
            <th>CKTID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>      
    {% for item in output.parsed %}
        <tr>
        {% if 'CID' in item.DESCRIP %}
            <td>{{inventory_hostname}}</td>
            <td>{{item.PORT}}</td>
            <td>{{item.DESCRIP}}</td>  
        {%elif 'ckid' in item.DESCRIP %}
            <td>{{inventory_hostname}}</td>
            <td>{{item.PORT}}</td>
            <td>{{item.DESCRIP}}</td>               
        {% endif %}    
     {% endfor %}   
        </tr>      
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

'output.parsed' has below info

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [host-1] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "DESCRIP": "CID: xxxx",
            "PORT": "Gi0/0/0",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        },
        {
            "DESCRIP": "",
            "PORT": "Gi0/0/1",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        },
        {
            "DESCRIP": "",
            "PORT": "Gi0/0/2",
            "PROTOCOL": "down",
            "STATUS": "down"
        },
        {
            "DESCRIP": "ckid: XXXX",
            "PORT": "Gi0/0/3",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [host-2] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "DESCRIP": "CID: xxxx",
            "PORT": "Gi0/0/1",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        },
        {
            "DESCRIP": "",
            "PORT": "Gi0/0/6",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        },
        {
            "DESCRIP": "",
            "PORT": "Gi0/0/7",
            "PROTOCOL": "down",
            "STATUS": "down"
        },
        {
            "DESCRIP": "ckid: XXXX",
            "PORT": "Gi0/0/8",
            "PROTOCOL": "up",
            "STATUS": "up"
        }
    ]
}
```

issue i have is - when i run playbook , cktreport.html is generated for just host-1,
i have multiple hosts, how to generate **single/one** cktreport.html such a way that it has all hosts info in it.

i know i need to modify jinja2 template but not sure what logic to use.

Comment: You are using `run_once`. The task will only run on first host in play. If you fix that, you will get an other problem: the report will be overwritten for each host since you use the same filename (this time you will only get last). You need to make the filename depending on the host you are generating for (e.g. `dest: /cktreport-{{ inventory_hostname }}.html`). Or are you looking for a way to generate one single report file for all host looping on a consolidated `output.parsed` for all of them?

Comment: @Zeitounator yes  - i am looking a way to generate one single report file for all host looping on a consolidated output.parsed for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take for granted your playbook targets the magic group `all`. Just replace in the template below with the correct group if this is not the case.

If you are doing something more complex (targeting several groups, using an advance host pattern, using limits on the command line...) have a look at [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) like `ansible_play_hosts` which will be more adapted.

It is in most cases a bad practice to loop directly on host lists outside of the natural play host loop... except when there is a good reason and this one. In your template, you need to go over all hosts to include in the report then loop on the parsed info you previously gathered. I believe the following template should meet your requirements (untested).

Notes:

- since `h` actually contains the `inventory_hostname`, I used it directly for conciseness. But you can replace with `hostvars[h].inventory_hostname` if you prefer. The result will be absolutely identical.
- your example template was not valid (closing `endfor` hanging arround with no opennig `for`). I fixed that below.
- I left your `if` stanza as they were but you have several options to DRY here and check both conditions at once (with the [`match` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) or other regexp solutions...) to output the same piece of html afterwards. I'll let you explore that on your own if you wish.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>HOSTNAME</th>
            <th>PORT</th>
            <th>CKTID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for h in groups['all'] %}     
    {% for item in hostvars[h].output.parsed %}
        <tr>
        {% if 'CID' in item.DESCRIP %}
            <td>{{ h }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.PORT }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.DESCRIP }}</td>  
        {%elif 'ckid' in item.DESCRIP %}
            <td>{{ h }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.PORT }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.DESCRIP }}</td>               
        {% endif %}      
        </tr>      
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```